# AWK: Get the value of the key if key founds in the file

Tags: awk

I have below file1

```
30012516|Geralyn|test|1010029|9985|0029|50|00|OneTime|1227065|2013-03-04|||||||Code4
30013017|tamara|test|3440029|1114|029|41|00|OneTime|1239244|2013-03-04|||||||Code3
30015518|daniel|test|3140029L|6440|0029|99|00|OneTime|1239306|2013-03-03|||||||Code2
30050011|first|test|1240030|1745|030|96|00|OneTime|1284010|2013-02-22|||||||Code1
10010905|madhu|com|5230029|614|029|29|10|OneTime|1293016|2013-03-04|||||||Code5
```

I want to search $18 (i.e. code{x}) in below file2, and if match is found then output the corresponding value of file2

```
Code1=Results of code1
Code3=Results of code3 
Code2=Results of code2
Code5=Results of code5
Code6=Results of code6
Code4=Results of code4
Code7=Results of code7
Code8=Results of code8
Code9=Results of code9
Code10=Results of code10
```

Then final output would be

```
Results of code4
Results of code3
Results of code2
Results of code1
Results of code5
```

I tried below grep command to get the value of the corresponding key

```
"(grep '"$18"=' file2 | cut -d'=' -f2)" | getline result
```

It was working fine, but for few keys its not returning the proper value. Is there any other way to get the proper result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this awk approach:

```
awk -F= 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2; next} $NF in A{print A[$NF]}' file2 FS=\| file1
```